# RabbitMQ Connection exception in Java Client

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using the RabbitMQ 3.6.12 version with java 8 client. I'm getting a frequent exception in the RabbitMQ log and my client is getting exited to consume the message.

logs on the RabbitMQ:

> =WARNING REPORT==== 29-DEC-2018::16:02:38 === closing AMQP connection <0.8979.3> (127.0.0.1:57065 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, vhost: '/', user:
>   'guest'): client unexpectedly closed TCP connection

logs on the Java Client:

```
[com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler] (AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672)
An unexpected connection driver error occured: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:164)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:580)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"
```